# xslt 1.0 template that reduces multiple spaces to a single space

Tags: xslt

In my XSLT 2.0 stylesheet, I use the following template reduces multiple spaces to a single space.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s+', ' ')"/>    
</xsl:template>
```

I'd like to do the same thing in a XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, but the "replace" function is not supported. Any suggestions for what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `normalize-space()`:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>  
</xsl:template>
```

This will remove any leading and trailing whitespace and reduce multiple spaces to a single space.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space